# How to format the background color of cell in condformat

Tags: r, shiny, formatting

```
sTable <<- condformat(sTable) %>% 
      rule_css(SafetyScore, expression = ifelse(SafetyScore > 4, "darkgreen",
                                            ifelse(SafetyScore >= 3 & SafetyScore < 4, "lightgreen",
                                            ifelse(SafetyScore >= 2 & SafetyScore < 3, "yellow",
                                            ifelse(SafetyScore >= 1 & SafetyScore < 2,"lightred",
                                                  "red")))), css_field = "color")
```

Above code works but it formats the text. I need to format the background. Is there any way I can do it?

Comment: I don't know which packages you are using (I've never seen `condformat` and `rule_ccs`), but I would try `css_field = "background-color"`.

Comment: Please consider providing a reproducible example for us to be able to help you. As a helping guide for this and future questions take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to use `css-field = "background-color"` in your `rule_css` and it will format the background instead of the text.